# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Activity.isDestroyed below Api 17 handle

Tags: android, android-savedstate

My app support min version api 15. And `isDestroyed()` method support min api 17.

So when I use this method **no such method error** below api 17.

User press home button and use other apps. After open my app activity instance is destroyed and when I use this activity instance, I get an error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(Unknown Source)
```

What can I do?

Comment: in fragment check isAdded() to check whether fragment is added layout.
Also your error "IllegalStateException" is because you are doing fragment transaction after onSaveInstanceState method of activity is completed. if you can ignore fragment transaction after completing some events the its good else you can manage one flag in the fragment for the onSaveInstanceState call, at time of fragment transaction if this is true then just skip the transaction and set one frag so in resume method you can popback stack if flag is set...Hope its works for you...

Answer (score 3):

You are probably commiting a fragment after onSaveInstanteState or from some other location where android cannot guarantee that it will be able to restore state.

You can use instead [`commitAllowingStateLoss()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss()) and dont use `isDestroyed()`. I suppose you could also check `getActivity()` for null, and commit only if it is non null. It will be null if fragment was detached.

[edit]

You could also use support library which provides this method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#isDestroyed()

(strange but from your exception it looks like you are using support library)

Comment: Yes, i use support library.

Comment: then check if you are using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().isDestroyed();`

Comment: if user's phone below api 17, i get an error no such method error. And may be getAcitivity() return null.

Comment: `getActivity` call is not needed. Inside `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` derived class you can use directly `getFragmentManager()` which returns `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
I created a boolean variable `destroyed` in the activity and set it in `onDestroy()` to `true`, in `onCreate()` to `false`. Then I checked at your point after the variable `destroyed` instead of calling the method `isDestroyed()`, which is not working.

I know this may not be the best solution and it is probably to late for you, but it works for me and I hope I can help others.